# Why cobalt performs much better than chromium in Youtube on embedded system like STB？

Tags: chromium, cobalt

Could anybody please tell me, compared to chromium, what is the simplification of the cobalt to fit the embedded system of the set-top box for better display?

Answer (score 0):

Because Cobalt supports only a subset of Web APIs, it is able to optimize and make assumptions that a general browser cannot make.  For example, only non-layout-inducing CSS properties are animatable, so Cobalt can assume that all animation updates are safe to be performed on a thread separate from the main layout/JavaScript thread.  By specifically targeting web apps that fit on one page, Cobalt can avoid supporting features like scrolling, allowing it to avoid caching as many rendered results in memory to save on memory.

Comment: Thank you man，it helps a lot！I'm wondering if Cobalt has also made many changes to the architecture of Chromium like CC and multiprocess architecture？Does Cobalt also simplify them a lot？And any other parts？